# Code won't work in script, but will work in the developer console

Tags: javascript, html

This is probably some strange glitch or whatever, but I've been stuck on this.

I'm writing a single line of code which is

```js
document.getElementById('joinTIMEdemo').innerHTML = new Date;
```

`<p id="joinTIMEdemo"></p>`
It is giving me an error which is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". I have checked many times, changing the name of the ID (in the javascript and html page) over and over again and I still get the same error.

I put the code that keeps troubling me into the developer console, and instead of just an error, it actually works, though when I put it in the script, it's spitting errors at me.

I've changed it from

`document.getElementById('joinTIMEdemo').innerHTML = new Date;`
to
`document.getElementById('joinTIME').innerHTML = new Date;`
to
`document.getElementById('loginTime').innerHTML = new Date;`
And so many other names to the point where it seems like Chrome is forgetting how to read my scripts.

I've rewritten the line of code countless times with no changes. I seriously need help. If I can get an answer, I will be so thankful.

Thanks in advance!

Note: Drag13 solved it in the comments. Apparently the html has to load before the scripts :/

Comment: please share the `HTML` of the element you're trying to access

Comment: does this `joinTIMEdemo` element exist in page source code of that page? (that means does it exist or it's created after some time - ajax event?

Comment: Try a button who starts a function which changes the wished innerHTML when pressed.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML?

Comment: Most of all, you are loading you script before this element appears in DOM. Move script to the bottom and do double check

Comment: So the `<script>` element with the Javascript code and the `<p>` element with that ID are in the same HTML, right?

Comment: Is there any script that is taking more time to load and delaying this view to render? If yes, than you should do this only after you have got response from backend.

Comment: @Drag13 Thank you, this solved it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your script gets executed after the page is interactive. There are two ways of doing this. The first would be to move your `script` tag to the bottom of the `body` tag so that the script gets executed after the browser "knows" what's in the DOM.

The other option would be to use the `onload` event on the window or the `readystatechange` event on the document to test when the document is interactive.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('joinTIMEdemo').innerHTML = new Date();
}
```

Comment: The second mechanism is the more reliable. In general, the "top level" of my `<script>` scripts doesn't contain any executable code except one assignment: to the  onload event of an anonymous function whose body is the code I actually want to execute.

Comment: A script at the bottom should be just as reliable as the DOM should be entirely parsed before any script starts getting parsed and executed.